# Bind to Decimal in ironPython

Tags: wpf, mvvm, ironpython

I'm having problems binding to a Decimal in IronPython

Here's a sample code (am using [Bojan Delic's IronPythonMVVM Library](https://github.com/delicb/mvvm) wich i haven't discarded as being part of the issue yet)

```
from decimal import *
class MyObject(ViewModel):
    .....
    value = Notifiable(Decimal('0.0'))
```

And then in XAML:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="5" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="3" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=results}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <WrapPanel>
                ....
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=value, StringFormat=N2}" />
            </WrapPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

And instead of the value in the object, i am getting

```
IronPython.NewTypes.System.Object_1$1
```

Obviously i am getting the object type rather then the decimal value that the object should be representing. Binding it to a DecimalUpDown from the Xceed.WPF.ToolKit library, shows an empty input, although if i place a value or use the up/down buttons, it will then show a value and place that value in the underlying object.
So why can't i display the object's value?

Comment: I'd suggest removing your edit, adding the solution below as an answer (without the question) and ask another question about this binding dealie.  But I'd wager that the binding doesn't "know" how to handle IP's decimal type, and that if you called ToString (or equiv) on IP's decimal you'd get "IronPython.NewTypes.System.Object_1$1"

Comment: yes - ToString gives me that while str(<decimal here>) gives ne the value

Comment: Yeah, WPF doesn't know anything about IronPython types.  If it doesn't recognize it as a primitive .net type, it'll call ToString on it.  So you'll need to create a ValueConverter, if IronPython (or someone else, check nuget) doesn't supply them.

Comment: thanks @Will - that's probably it

Comment: Creating custom converters isn't hard--someone probably already did it for IP.  Or, do a little search here and you'll find many examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

removing the `from decimal import *` line and replacing the `'0.0'` with `0` in the `Decimal` constructor makes it all work correctly. from what i understand, i am now using `System.Decimal` from .NET rather than IronPython's own Decimal type.